# React Redux "Cannot read property 'status' of undefined" error when trying to access store variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on an app to teach myself React and Redux and I am running into an issue when trying to access the variables that have been added to the store.

I am able to add data to the store object and verify that the data is there by using console.log but when I try to drill down to the actual variable I want to access I am getting an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined".

When viewing the state I can see that the status is there:
{"customerInfo":[],"loginInfo":[],"storeStatus":[{"status":false}]}

but then trying to access anything within state.storeStatus[0] (example:  state.storeStatus[0].status) returns the error of being undefined.

Is there a different way that I should be trying to access that variable if I want to assign it to a new variable to be used in some conditional rendering?

storeStatusReducers.js

```js
import deepFreeze from 'deep-freeze'

const state = [];
const storeStatusReducer = (state = true, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case 'STORE_STATUS_UPDATE':
        state = [];  
        return [...state, action.data]
      default:
      return state
    }
  }

 export const updateStoreStatusAction = (status) => {
    return {
      type: 'STORE_STATUS_UPDATE',
      data: {
        status
      }
    }
  }

  deepFreeze(state)
  export default storeStatusReducer;
```

home.js

```js
import React,  { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { updateStoreStatusAction } from '../reducers/storeStatusReducers' 
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const storeInfo = {
  storeId : "1337",
  storeStatus: true
}

const HomePage = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const storeStatusData = useSelector(state => state.storeStatus);

  let payload = {
    storeId: storeInfo.storeId,
  };
  useEffect(() => {
  axios({
    url: "/api/get-test-data/" + storeInfo.storeId,
    method: "GET",
    data: payload,
  })
    .then((data) => {
     console.log("data.data.storeStatusPayload", JSON.stringify(data.data.storeStatusPayload))
     updateStoreStatus(data.data.storeStatusPayload);
     
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("changeStoreStatus: Internal server error");
    });
  }, []);

  const updateStoreStatus = (updatedStoreStatus) => {
    dispatch(updateStoreStatusAction(updatedStoreStatus));
  };

  //This works and produces: {"status":false}
  console.log("storeStatusData", JSON.stringify(storeStatusData[0]))
  // This does not when trying to access status
  console.log("storeStatusData", JSON.stringify(storeStatusData[0].status))


  return (
    <div>
      <main>
      <h1>Test App</h1>

      </main>    
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Update:
This is working now. Thanks!

Updated home.js

```js
import React,  { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { updateStoreStatusAction } from '../reducers/storeStatusReducers' 
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const storeInfo = {
  storeId : "1337",
  storeStatus: true
}

const HomePage = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const storeStatusData = useSelector(state => state.storeStatus);

  let payload = {
    storeId: storeInfo.storeId,
  };
  useEffect(() => {
  axios({
    url: "/api/get-test-data/" + storeInfo.storeId,
    method: "GET",
    data: payload,
  })
    .then((data) => {
     console.log("data.data.storeStatusPayload", JSON.stringify(data.data.storeStatusPayload))
     updateStoreStatus(data.data.storeStatusPayload);
     
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("changeStoreStatus: Internal server error");
    });
  }, []);

  const updateStoreStatus = (updatedStoreStatus) => {
    dispatch(updateStoreStatusAction(updatedStoreStatus));
  };

  //This works and produces: {"status":false}
  console.log("storeStatusData", JSON.stringify(storeStatusData[0]))
  // This does not when trying to access status
  console.log("storeStatusData", JSON.stringify(storeStatusData[0].status))

  const renderLoadingBar = () => {
    if (storeStatusData[0] ) {
      return (
        <div>
          loaded
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        // table container
        <div>
        loading
         </div> 
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <main>
      <h1>Test App</h1>
<div>{renderLoadingBar()}</div>
      </main>    
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: The initial state is an empty array, so `storeStatusData[0]` is `undefined`. The reason why it looks like it's working with `storeStatusData[0]` is either the console evaluating the value later on while you're inspecting it in the console (chrome does this), or it logs twice, once as `undefined` and once as the object.

Comment: And since you're using `JSON.stringify`, I'd lean towards the 2 logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your effect is running asynchronously, your data will not be available on initial render. That means trying to access a prop on the nonexistent array element will cause your app to crash.

The fact that your initial log statement *appears* to work is mosty likely because it's `undefined` on the initial render but then the expected value on the second render. On the other hand, your second `console.log` statement fails immediately and you never make it to a subsequent render.

To prevent this issue from happening, a common pattern is to use a short-circuit evaluation. For example:

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
  // (initial component code here)

  // Only log if the array element exists
  storeStatusData[0] && console.log("storeStatusData", JSON.stringify(storeStatusData[0].status))


  return (
    <div>
      <main>
      <h1>Test App</h1>

      </main>    
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense however when I set up something to test that it looks like the data is being overwritten and becoming undefined. I put a loading bar to display  if (storeStatusData[0] ) and else display some text. The text displays briefly and then it goes back to the loading bar screen which tells me storeStatusData[0] has become undefined again.

Comment: Can you update the question with the issue you're hitting now? It's a bit hard to follow what's going on.

Comment: The question has been updated with the new code I mention in my above comment.

Comment: Looks like you might have the logic reversed? It should be loaded if the array element exists

Comment: Yes you are totally right. I think it is working as expected now. Thanks!

Comment: @dylanlarrivee awesome!